# URL link Cardboard and youtube Android

Tags: android, youtube, google-cardboard

I am trying to open a 360video from unity without using a “VideoTexture”, which means to use a URL and then, select the “cardboard experience”.

My question is if it is a way of launching directly the youtube application with the link of the youtube video (360) from Android, which will display the video in full screen using the gyroscope data.
Please write to michael.soler.beatty@gmail.com if needed

The video is
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EhueMB9EzoE

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

This android code must be work:

```
public static void watchYoutubeVideo(String id){
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("vnd.youtube:" + id));
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + id));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

You can write an android unity plugin or use android jni inside Unity.